# Why the second character is getting lost for the second variable

Tags: c++, string, char, getline

I have 2 variables of `char` type.

```
char desc[30];
char code[2];
cout << "Enter values : "<<"\n";
cin.getline(desc,30);
cin.getline(code,2);

cout << "\nValues Entered: "<<"\n";
cout << desc <<"\t";
cout << code <<"\n";
```

When the input values are provided as below, the second character for the second variable is lost. I have tried `cin>>marks` and `cin.get(marks,2)`, but the behaviour is always same.

```
Enter values :
This is a test line
LH

Values Entered:
This is a test line     L

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 11.285 s
Press any key to continue.
```

In the example above even though the input is `LH`, in the output only 'L' is available and 'H' is lost. Can someone advise what is wrong here?

Comment: _"I have 2 variables of char type."_ No, you don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) (emphasis mine):

> Maximum number of characters to write to s **(including the terminating
>   null character)**.

So if you want to read in two symbols, you have to put a size of `3`.

```
cin.getline(code,3);
```

Change your buffer size to `3`, too:

```
char code[3];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.